# Plotting the spectra, Mean of Photoacoustic signals, remove the background

Tags: environment-variables, spyder, spectral-python

I have my data with more then 10 columns in which one column represents the data on x-axis (laser) while the rest of them represents the output frequency peaks. So i want to take the mean of the signal and then to remove the background. So, anybody knows how we do this in python please?

Actually, its my first month in research with this program but what i know about my result to get the spectra of our sample by removing the noise and to get their mean.